# MATLAB - how to read big size multiband TIFF witout loading to memory

Tags: image, matlab, memory, load, tiff

I have a 1675x965x365 TIFF image (>2GB) which is too large to import in MATLAB without having my computer slowing down tremendously (so far I wasn't able to open it neither!). Is there an efficient way to read my image without having to load it to memory (which I suppose is the problem)? Anyway, my final aim would be to sum the values of each band with the other bands, that is to have a 2D image 1675x965 in size with (e.g.) pixel in [1,1] that is the sum of all the pixels of the 365 bands in position [1,1]. I hope to have explained my problem cleaarly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using the indexing ability of `imread ()` keeps you from never having more than two planes worth of data loaded at any one time:

```
ImgInfo = imfinfo('imgFile.tif');

BaseImg = zeros(ImgInfo(1).Width, ImgInfo(1).Height);

for k = 1:length(ImgInfo)

    BaseImg = BaseImg + double(imread('imgFile.tif', k, 'Info', ImgInfo));

end

BaseImg = BaseImg/length(ImgInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a matlab class for lazy loading of TIFF images; the data is left on disk, and only loaded when accessed. That should take care of your memory issues. See if it helps you.

[Lazy loading of TIFF stacks for Matlab](http://dylan-muir.com/articles/tiffstack/)